# PHP formula to prevent exceeding http requests from an IP

Tags: php, security, formula, brute-force

I am going to prevent hackers from scanning my website pages , I invented a formula to control average hits in a time span , is it the best solution?

```
function exceeded(){
  $limit=5;
  $span=15;
  $now=time();
  if($now-$_SESSION['lastDate']>=$span){
     $_SESSION['lastDate']=$now;
     $_SESSION['totalHits']=1;
     return false;
  }
  $_SESSION['totalHits']=($_SESSION['totalHits']*($span-($now-$_SESSION['lastDate'])))/$span;
  $_SESSION['totalHits']+=1; // Adds current Hit
  if($_SESSION['totalHits']<=$limit){
      $_SESSION['lastDate']=$now;
      return false;
   }
   $_SESSION['lastDate']=$now;
   return true;
}
//-----------------------------
if(exceeded()){
  echo 'You have exceeded your request limit come back in 15 seconds';
  exit;
}
```

Comment: Try to do this with the webserver (e.g. mod_security for apache), not with php. Your code depends on a session - probably recognized by a cookie - if i don't send a cookie, my 'totalHits' will not go up...

Comment: Try to take the security in the webserver, not in the php logic...

Comment: @Ste Bächler I attached each session to usernames so if they clean sessions they will log out

Comment: so you'll will get even more traffic with this script - just imagine what happens if someone want to scan your site, and does a login before each page-scan...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are still going to execute PHP code which needs CPU/RAM/... so a better way to do this is through limiting requests handled by the server. If you are afraid of a user DDoSing your server try using a service like Cloudflare.

If you are using Apache, read up onto [mod_evasive](http://systembash.com/content/how-to-stop-an-apache-ddos-attack-with-mod_evasive/), Nginx users can [limit the rate requests](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#limit_rate) get through.

Why PHP is also not a good choice? A DDoS tool will not storage cookies and this moment you are actually using the storage of your clients computer to remember his visits. If you really want to do it in PHP you should check on the users IP and use a database of his requests (which also takes CPU/RAM everytime he visits).

Comment: My main propose is prevent scanning forms to find sql bugs , is mod_evasive configuring good for prevent acunetix to scan my pages?

Comment: The safest way to make sure sql bugs (like sql injections) don't work is using the correct PDO::Mysql tools like prepare and bindParam which will make your live in security easier.

Comment: Can i prevent acunetix to scan my pages with  mod_evasive method?

Comment: Don't think you can stop any program from scanning your pages as long as it can act as a normal user. You can check useragents (which are easily spoofed by this sort of scanners), you can check the time of requests (they got time-outs between requests options),... the only way to make sure your application is secure is by making sure a user can't do anything except what you allow.

Comment: You helped so much Thank you Tom

Comment: @JoeBlack: if you think you might have security problems, the best thing to do is to track them down. Yes, `mod_security` and other tools might help, but that isn't nearly as effective. You can also operate your own stateful firewall (on another machine) to prevent excess load reaching your PHP server (similar to the third-party service Cloudflare that Tom mentions).